# Lesser known security pitfalls in Python

Tags: python, secure-coding

I recently came across this article: https://blog.sonarsource.com/10-unknown-security-pitfalls-for-python, which describes security pitfalls in the python programming language that are less well known to developers.

Do you have examples of other security-sensitive built-in features that exist in Python that many developers overlook?

To be clear, I am not referring to features that are inherently dangerous, for example:

1. exec
2. eval
3. system
4. APIs used for deserialization (though this might be a grey area)

In general, my question refers to features, where the behaviour is not "expected" from the perspective of the programmer, such as `input()` in python2, which evaluates the user's input.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question, while interesting, does not really have a single, specific answer. Such questions are not really suitable for the StackExchange sites.

Comment: Less known than what and for who? This question is highly subjective and very broad. Even after tailoring it to a specific language, you should at least provide a list of what you consider "known" security pitfalls.